# Wait for element to render after an *ngIf in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

Is there a way to wait for a HTML element to render after it has been enabled because of an `*ngIf` ?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwpfwx-u6xd7j?file=app/select-overview-example.ts) to show what I mean exactly.

I can't do `document.getElementById('someid')` if I just toggled the condition of the `*ngIf` on an element. Is there a callback/way to call the code just after the element has been rendered?

I just want it called on a specific element, so I can't just use ngAfterViewChecked().

Comment: did you try with [hidden] , <div id="someid" [hidden]="render">?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do html render first setting the function into a setTimeout

```
if(this.render) {
  setTimeout( () => document.getElementById('someid').focus());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this blitz: https://angular-hwpfwx-xvmbiv.stackblitz.io
Open the console to see the reference to the div.

It uses `ViewChild` to detect the same `div` using `ngIf`.

Comment: this doesn't load. Please provide solutions on stackoverflow rather than other sites.